# Migration from Samba to Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We want to migrate Samba domain controller and webmail to Windows Server 2012 R2. Our Windows Server 2012 R2 will be hosted on VMware server. I have zero knowledge of it, so my question is what the best way of creating two domain controllers is. Active Directory? Basically, there should be around 15 groups.

Domain controllers example:

- groupa.sitedomain.com
- groupb.sitedomain.com

I found a way to migrate all samba accounts by parsing `/etc/passwd` using C#. You might say what about people's passwords. They are going to be randomly generated and people will be notified about that.

**Summary:**

1st question. I would like to get tips on how to build the domain controllers? Take me as a novice. I know there is a lot of information but that's the problem because I can't summarize all of it.

2nd question. What about the webmail? All I know about is that those domain accounts will be used in the webmail as well but I have no clue how to host the service.

Comment: I would suggest you let someone else take a look at what would be suitable for your particular situation as this can be configured in a myriad of ways. The best way is completely dependent on what you need exactly and how the old farm is configured... To be very honest... If you have 0 knowledge of it, any comprehensive answer that would cover even the most basic scenarios here would be very, very long...

Comment: @BloodPhilia, I just need to set up the server with both domain controllers and user accounts as an active directory. And eventually something to host the webmails on. Could you refer me to additional information that I can read?